# regex: Match and replace all X400 addresses (delimited by semi-colons) within a line of other entities delimited by a semi-colon

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to parse an export of my corporate directory and am having trouble because of the semi-colon handling of the export.  Each line of the export data contains a distinguishedName for a user and then one or more email addresses (sip,smtp,x400) associated with that user.  I've been trying to identify a regex that I can use to match all the x400 addresses within a line and then replace the semi-colons within the x400 address with commas. The x400 address is displayed in this format `x400:c=us\;a= \;p=company\;o=Exchange\;s=lastName\;g=firstName\;` Replacing the semi-colons in only the X400 address would give me a line that would be properly delimited, thus I could use script to parse the data further.
Here is my export data:

```
CN=Doe\\, Jane,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;sip:jdoe@company.com;smtp:jdoe@company-b.com;smtp:Jane.Doe@company.com;SMTP:JDoe@company.com;X400:c=us\;a= \;p=Company\;o=Exchange\;s=Doe\;g=Jane\;
CN=Smith\\, Mike,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;sip:msmith@company.com;x400:c=us\;a= \;p=COMPANY\;o=Exchange\;s=Smith\;g=Mike\;;smtp:MSmith@company-b.com;smtp:Mike.Smith@company.com;X400:c=us\;a= \;p=COMPANY\;o=Exchange\;s=Smith\;g=Mike\;;SMTP:msmith@compnay.com;smtp:MmSmith@company.com;smtp:Mike.Smith@company.com;smtp:MSmith@company-b.com;smtp:Mike.Smith@company.com
CN=Jones\\, Barbara,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;BJones@company.com;SMTP:BRJoenes@company.com;sip:BrJoes@company.com
CN=Bay\\, Matt,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC MBay@company.com;sip:MBay@company.com
CN=O'Connor\\, Sam,OU=Visitor,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;sip:SO'Connor@company.com;x400:c=us\;a= \;p=COMPANY\;o=Exchange\;s=O'Connor\;g=Sam\;;so'connor@company-b.com
```

I'm looking for a regex replace that would result in the export data looking like this...

```
CN=Doe\\, Jane,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;sip:jdoe@company.com;smtp:jdoe@company-b.com;smtp:Jane.Doe@company.com;SMTP:JDoe@company.com;X400:c=us\,a= \,p=Company\,o=Exchange\,s=Doe\,g=Jane\,;
CN=Smith\\, Mike,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;sip:msmith@company.com;x400:c=us\,a= \,p=COMPANY\,o=Exchange\,s=Smith\,g=Mike\,;smtp:MSmith@company-b.com;smtp:Mike.Smith@company.com;X400:c=us\,a= \,p=COMPANY\,o=Exchange\,s=Smith\,g=Mike\,;SMTP:msmith@compnay.com;smtp:MmSmith@company.com;smtp:Mike.Smith@company.com;smtp:MSmith@company-b.com;smtp:Mike.Smith@company.com
CN=Jones\\, Barbara,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;BJones@company.com;SMTP:BRJoenes@company.com;sip:BrJoes@company.com
CN=Bay\\, Matt,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC MBay@company.com;sip:MBay@company.com
CN=O'Connor\\, Sam,OU=Visitor,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;sip:SO'Connor@company.com;x400:c=us\,a= \,p=COMPANY\,o=Exchange\,s=O'Connor\,g=Sam\,;so'connor@company-b.com
```

I'm using PowerShell regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex to replace the substring:

```
$callback = {  
    Param
    (
        $match
    ) 

    '{0}' -f ($match.Groups[1].Value -replace ';', ',')
}

$txt = 'CN=Doe\\, Jane,OU=Employee,OU=Production,OU=Users,DC=COMPANY,DC=LOC;sip:jdoe@company.com;smtp:jdoe@company-b.com;smtp:Jane.Doe@company.com;SMTP:JDoe@company.com;X400:c=us\;a= \;p=Company\;o=Exchange\;s=Doe\;g=Jane\;'

$rex = [regex]'(X400:.*?g=.+?\\)'
$rex.Replace($txt, $callback)
```

Comment: Martin, your suggestion works great when there is a single x400 address within a line, but if there are multiple such as my "Mike Smith" example, it doesn't seem to work.  Is there a way to get the regex to match on both x400 addresses and then process them individually with $match?

Comment: Sure, its because one address is using X and one x. So just change the regex to : `([X|x]400:.*?g=.+?\\)`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
... -replace 'x400:([a-z]*=.*?\\;)*(;|$)'
```

Comment: Ansgar, your suggestion seems to work if there is only one x400 entry in the line, but if there are two like the "Mike Smith" example, it doesn't appear to match on both of them.  Do you have any suggestions on how the regex can be defined so that it matches on all x400 addresses?

Comment: My original answer did not cover X.400 addresses at the end of a string (which is now corrected). Other than that it will remove any X.400 address present in a string. If it doesn't work for you: please provide evidence.

Answer (score 1):

> Replacing the semi-colons in only the X400 address would give me a line that would be properly delimited, thus I could use script to parse the data further.

You could also just take the X400 format into account when parsing the data:

```
Get-Content data.txt |ForEach-Object {
    $DN,$AddressString = $_ -split ';',2

    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        DistinguishedName = $DN
        Addresses = $AddressString -split ';(?=\w+:)'
    }
}
```